# Define a Zend Model as Singleton

Tags: php, zend-framework, constructor, singleton

I want to put my Zend Model as Singleton, so I have done this:

```
class Social_Model_DbTable_Dossier extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

private static $_instance;

public static function GetInstance() {
    if (!self::$_instance instanceof self) {
        self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

private function __construct() {
    // put normal constructor code.
    // it will only ever be called once
}}
```

I instantiate my model like so:

```
        $dossiercasModel =  Social_Model_DbTable_Dossier::GetInstance();
```

but this erreur is occured:

```
Fatal error: Access level to Social_Model_DbTable_Dossier::__construct() must be public (as in class Zend_Db_Table_Abstract)
```

when I put the constructor of the Model as public it works fine but this is  inconsistent with the notion of singleton!

Comment: **The error occurs because you can't change the Access level for a override method.** `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::__construct()` is set as public so you can't have your own `__construct()` function as private if you're extending that class.

Comment: So, can I set the constructor of the model as public? And when i do this, the notion of singleton persist?

Comment: As long as you always use `Social_Model_DbTable_Dossier::GetInstance` and never `new Social_Model_DbTable_Dossier` you'll only have one instance of your class.

Comment: You shouldn't overload the constructor for a Zend_Db_Table object instead put your custom code in the init method.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have gotten arround having to do this by creating a table broker that would serve up cached table instances,
kind of a multiton.

a simple example

```
class My_TableManager{

   protected static $_instance;
   protected $_tableCache = array();

   protected function __construct(){

   }

   public static function getInstance(){
       if (!isset(self::$_instance)) self::$_instance = new self();
   }

   public function getTable($tableName){
        if (!array_key_exists($tableName, $this->_tableCache)){
            // you can do fun stuff here like name inflection
            // Im assuming that tables will be suffixed with _Table
            $tableClass = "My_".$tableName."_Table";
            $this->_tableCache[$tableName] = new $tableClass();
        }
        return $this->_tableCache[$tableName];
   }

   public static function get($tableName){
        return self::getInstance()->getTable($tableName);
   }
}
```

To use  to get an instance of My_User_Table you would could:

```
$table = My_TableManager::get("My_User");
```

or

```
$table = My_TableManager::getInstnace()->getTable("My_Table");
```